# Uso de printf e scanf no Eclipse e Netbeans - Linguagem C

Tags: c, eclipse, netbeans, scanf, printf

Boa noite. 
Tenho o programa abaixo que solicita ao usuário a inserção de 2 números e depois os apresentam. No Code Blocks está funcionando corretamente, porém quando executo no Eclipse ou no Netbeans, o sistema fica aguardando a digitação dos números sem a apresentação das mensagens no printf. Alguém sabe como resolver?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int num1, num2;

printf ("Digite o primeiro numero: ");

scanf("%d", &num1);

printf ("Digite o segundo numero: ");

scanf("%d", &num2);

printf ("Os números diigitados foram %d e %d.", num1, num2);

return 0;

}
```

Resultado do console:

```
5
5
Digite o primeiro numero: Digite o segundo numero: Os números digitados        
foram 5 e 5.
```

Comment: Executei seu programa e não apareceu nada de errado, [veja](https://repl.it/repls/UnrulyAutomaticApache).

Comment: Pois é, no Code Blocks funciona normalmente mas no Eclipse e no NetBeans não. Deve ser algum problema com a configuração das IDE.

Comment: O que parece ter acontecido é que nessas IDEs ele está seguindo a bufferização padrão do `stdout`: imprimir ao ter um `\n` ou chegar no fim do programa. Se você por quebras de linhas (ou mudar a bufferização para ser byte a byte) deve obter um resultado melhor. Tem duas maneiras de testar isso: (a) pondo os `\n` em cada `printf` ou (b) mantendo as impressões do jeito que está, só que indo para `stderr`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mesmo incluindo o \n permanece com o mesmo problema, o console só apresenta as mensagens no printf após a digitação dos números. Não consegui usar o stderr, você pode me exemplificar?

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "o resto normalmente como printf");`

Comment: Digitei dessa forma mas não apresentou nenhum erro. O problema continuou.

Answer (score -2):

se for no **NETBEANS** Faz a execução pelo terminal externo, clica no projeto(dentro do netbeans) tecla direita properties(propriedades) -> procure a opção Run(Executar) > primeira coluna na opção tipo de Console lado direito mude a opção para terminal Externo.

Clique em aplicar lá em baixo e de um Ok.

Pronto execute irá aparecer a tela do DOS e vc conseguirá rodar normal.

**vídeo mostrando o passo a passo:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IelB0dRmr84&list=LL&index=7